# Azure Terraform related to using multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to use the public IP prefix in the production environment in the development environment. I wrote the code on provider.tf as follows.

- provider.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "testrg-tfstate"
    storage_account_name = "testrg-tfstate"
    container_name       = "testrg-tfstate"
    key                  = "testrg-tfstate.tfstate"
  }
}

# Dev
provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    resource_group {
      prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = true
    }
  }
  alias = "dev"
  subscription_id = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000"
  tenant_id       = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000"
  client_id       = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000"
  client_secret   = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000"
}

# Prd
provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    resource_group {
      prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = true
    }
  }
  alias = "prd"
  subscription_id = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000"
  tenant_id       = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000"
  client_id       = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000"
  client_secret   = "000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000"

}
```

- main.tf

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  provider = azurerm.dev
  name = var.kv_name
  resource_group_name = var.kv_rg
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "password" {
  provider = azurerm.dev
  name = var.kv_secret_name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "system_rg" {
  provider = azurerm.dev
  name     = var.system_rg
  location = var.location
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "system_rg_name" {
  provider = azurerm.dev
  name = azurerm_resource_group.system_rg.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "network_subnet" {
  provider = azurerm.dev
  name                 = var.network_subnet
  virtual_network_name = var.network_vnet
  resource_group_name  = var.network_rg
}

data "azurerm_public_ip_prefix" "azmercury_prefix01" {
  provider = azurerm.prd
  name  = var.prefix_pip01
  resource_group_name  = var.ip_prefix_rg
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  provider = azurerm.dev
  for_each                      = var.vm_template
  name                          = "${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.nic}"
  location                      = var.location
  resource_group_name           = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  enable_accelerated_networking = true
  
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.network_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = each.value.private-ip-type
    private_ip_address            = each.value.private_ip
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.pip[each.key].id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
  provider = azurerm.prd
  for_each            = var.vm_template
  name                = "vm-p-${each.value.hostname}-pip01"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  
  allocation_method   = "Static"

  sku                 = "Standard"
  public_ip_prefix_id = data.azurerm_public_ip_prefix.azmercury_prefix01.id
  domain_name_label   = each.value.hostname
  reverse_fqdn        = "${each.value.hostname}.test.com"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      reverse_fqdn,
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  provider = azurerm.dev
  for_each = var.vm_template
  name                = each.value.vm_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  source_image_id     = each.value.dev_source_image_id
  zone                = each.value.zone
  size = each.value.vm_type
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.nic[each.key].id,
  ]

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  os_disk {
    name                 = "${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.os_disk}"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = each.value.osdisk_type
    disk_size_gb         = each.value.osdisk_size
  }

  plan {
    name      = each.value.os_sku
    publisher = each.value.os_publisher
    product   = each.value.os_offer
  }

  computer_name  = each.value.hostname
  admin_username = var.adminid
  admin_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.password.value  
  disable_password_authentication = false

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      admin_password,
    ]
  }
}
```

Since the public IP prefix is created in the production environment, it seems that the public IP should be created in the development environment because the resource group cannot be found as shown below.

- error

```
azurerm_public_ip.pip["vm1"]: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating/updating Public Ip Address: (Name "vm-test-pip01" / Resource Group "test-resourcegroup"): network.PublicIPAddressesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: Code="ResourceGroupNotFound" Message="Resource group 'test-resourcegroup' could not be found."
│
│   with azurerm_public_ip.pip["vm1"],
│   on vm.tf line 67, in resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip":
│   67: resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
```

I need help. If anyone has the same concerns as me, please reply.

Comment: Can you explain more what you're trying to do? Why are you using the `prd` provider for the `azurerm_public_ip.pip` resource but trying to provision it in the `azurerm_resource_group.system_rg` resource group that you provisioned using the `dev` provider (presumably in a different subscription)?

The error message you're seeing makes sense to me - the `prd` provider scoped to the PRD subscription so it can't see the `azurerm_resource_group.system_rg` resource group in your DEV subscription?

Comment: There are production subscriptions and development subscriptions.
The public IP prefix is in the production subscription. I want to use the public IP prefix created in the production subscription in the development subscription. When I create a virtual machine in the development subscription, I think I'm getting an error when I try to use the public IP prefix ```azurerm_public_ip.pip```, which was created in the production subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating `system_rg`, you don't need to use data source `system_rg_name` to get its name. Its counter productive and can lead to errors. Just use name directly, e.g.:

```
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.system_rg.name
```

Comment: The issue now is that the public IP prefix is created in a production subscription, and the VM that you want to use this public IP prefix is a development subscription. @Marcin

Comment: The public IP prefix for subscription A does not appear to be available for subscription B. Please keep an eye on the item ```provider``.

Comment: There is no way to use ```provider=azurerm.dev``` and ```provider=azurerm.prd``` in ```azurerm_public_ip``` at the same time.